# Use IF conditional in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple `WHERE` clause like:

```
WHERE
    [T].[DesignKey] = 5232
    AND
    (
        [TT].[TaskTypeCategoryId] ='8f08640b-bc74-e811-80dc-509a4c609460'
        OR
        [TT].[TaskTypeCategoryId] = '15F1F492-0CAC-E811-8421-C81F66DACA6A'
    )
    AND
    [TA].[EmpKey] = 58
```

Now I want to filter if this condition is true `SecId > 4` filter by `[TA].[EmpKey] = 58` If not just don't apply this filter so I do like:

```
WHERE
    [T].[DesignKey] = 5232
    AND
    (
        [TT].[TaskTypeCategoryId] ='8f08640b-bc74-e811-80dc-509a4c609460'
        OR
        [TT].[TaskTypeCategoryId] = '15F1F492-0CAC-E811-8421-C81F66DACA6A'
    )
    AND
    (
        E.SecID > 4
        OR
        (
            [TA].[EmpKey] = 58
        )
    )
```

But it no works, it just don't applying filter if `SecId` comes with 5, what am I doing wrong? Regards

Comment: Sorry, I update my question @Dai

Comment: What is `E.SecID` exactly? What does your source data look like and what should the output look like? To confirm, you're not using any query parameters?

Comment: Does `[T].[DesignKey] = 5232` apply to every row?

Comment: Yes @Used_By_Already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it on your first attempt. You just have to add in a condition to allow for when SecID <= 4. You can add another couple of lines to do it with your original query, like this:

```
WHERE
    [T].[DesignKey] = 5232
    AND
    (
        [TT].[TaskTypeCategoryId] ='8f08640b-bc74-e811-80dc-509a4c609460'
        OR
        [TT].[TaskTypeCategoryId] = '15F1F492-0CAC-E811-8421-C81F66DACA6A'
    )
    AND
    (
        E.SecID <= 4
        OR
        (
            E.SecID > 4
            AND
            [TA].[EmpKey] = 58
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
WHERE
    [T].[DesignKey] = 5232
    AND
    (
        [TT].[TaskTypeCategoryId] ='8f08640b-bc74-e811-80dc-509a4c609460'
        OR
        [TT].[TaskTypeCategoryId] = '15F1F492-0CAC-E811-8421-C81F66DACA6A'
    )
    AND 
    (
        CASE WHEN E.SecID > 4 THEN [TA].[EmpKey] ELSE 58 END = 58
    )
```

If true, it'll filter with `EmpKey = 58`, if false it'll simply says `58 = 58` which will be always true.

Comment: Interesting trick - does it make the query non-SARGable though?

Comment: @Dai as per of my knowledge, no, as case statement is a T-SQL and not a function, in which the optimizer will convert it into ANDs and ORs. So, it'll be a SARG query.

Comment: Generally, a `CASE` expression will cause it to become non-SARGable, @Dai. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171337/case-statement-and-sargability-specific-use-case. The optimiser doesn't convert it to `AND` or `OR`s.

Comment: @Larnu in this case, need to dig more about CASE and non-SARGable, but I'm sure I've read somewhere that the optimizer converts it into ANDs and ORs to be a T-SQL statement, but I'll look into it. Also, I've just tested it, and I found out that it will use index scan and not index seek.

Comment: I can't say I've ever heard that a `CASE` expression is evaluated as an `OR`/`AND` before, and I've certainly never seen it in any work I've done. If you have some reference material on the matter, I'd be interested to see it @iSR5 . There might be some (very) specific `CASE` expression that are SARGable, and maybe that's the scenario you're thinking of otherwise? *(Of course, i mean where the `CASE` is on the column, not a variable. Something like `WHERE [Column] = CASE @Variable WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE @Variable END` is SARGable).*